# jQuery 1.9.1 ajax() json response: php with include

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, include

I have a problem with jQuery 1.9.1 and a json response.
My html-File is very simple for testing (working with jQuery 1.8.3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      $.ajax({
        url: "php/news_test.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json){
          $("#news-box").html(json.news.name);
        }
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="news-box"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works fine with the following php-File:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
include('core/database.php');
/*
$db = new Database();
...
...
...
*/
echo json_encode(array("news" => array("name" => "Test")));
```

But when I change to jQuery 1.9.1 I don't get a response.
I have to comment the seconde line `include('core/database.php');` After that I get a response with jQuery 1.9.1.
The database.php has only one line for testing `$db_host = 'localhost';`

Can't I use the include with jQuery 1.9.1?
Do I have an error in my code?
Or is it a bug?

Comment: maybe you have some whitespace in your database.php that is echo'd?

Comment: This is my database.php: <?php
  $db_host = 'localhost';
?> Without whitespace before and aftet the <? and ?>

Comment: Add an error callback and log the arguments (there are three of them, the 2nd and 3rd are what we're looking for.)

Comment: sorry, for this late answer. I get a error with code 200:
200:SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: FireBug tells me error 200 OK and the answer is {"news":{"name":"Test"}}

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem when simply upgrading jQuery to 1.9.1 (from 1.7.2, I believe).  Without changing any other code or the server, I began getting this error.  The way I solved it was to removed the line

```
dataType: "json",
```

from the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

I had what seems to be the same issue, and it was because the file must have been saved with the "Include Unicoi Signature (BOM)" checked in Dreamweaver. You have to resave the problem file WITHOUT that option (leave checkbox blank). see [this article](http://www.softmehard.com/beware-of-the-unicode-signature-bom/) for more info.